# ¿Cómo iniciar un timer desde otro formulario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer

Tengo un `Timer` que me carga información en un formulario `formulario1`, cuando desde el formulario uno abro otro formulario `formulario2`, detengo el `Timer` en `formulario2`, ahora ¿cómo puedo hacer para volver a iniciarlo desde el `formulario2`? ¿Algún ejemplo?

**EDIT: Formulario1 donde tengo el `Timer` e instancio el Formulario2 y detengo el `Timer`.**

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    metodocargadatos();
}
```

En mi evento del botón tengo:

```
Form2 viewnew = new Form2();
viewnew.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
viewnew.Show();
timer.Stop();
```

Comment: ¿Qué se te ha ocurrido, has intentado algo?

Comment: no tengo mucho codigo, solo tengo cuando lo inicio y me llama a un metod, en un evento del boton cuando abro el siguiente formulario este timer lo detengo, pero ahora como lo vuelvo a iniciar al cerrar el formalio2 para que vuelva a cargar la informacion? editare la pregunta para poner el codigo pero basicamente es lo que explico aqui.

Comment: Crea una instancia del formulario_1, cambia a publico el timer ,  y accede a la propiedad del timer con la instancia creada

Comment: @Manny agregue una posible solucion , me indicas si te fue util

Answer (score 4):

No aconsejor acceder directamente a los controles de otro form poniendo estos como publicos, ya que genera un alto acomplamiento.

Deberias usar `interfaces` o `eventos` para la comunicacion entre los forms

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

Entonces la idea es que en el form padre, en este caso el Form1 expones la interfaz

```
public interface IStartTimer{
    void Start();
}
```

entonces lo implementas

```
public class Form1 : Form, IStartTimer {

     public void Start(){
       timer.Start();
     }

     public void button1_Click(...)
     {
       Form2 viewnew = new Form2(this);
       viewnew.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
       viewnew.Show();
       timer.Stop();
     }

}
```

desde el Form2 invocas a la interfaz que enviaste en el constructor

```
 public class Form2 : Form {

     private IStartTimer _instance;

     public Form2(){
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     public Form2(IStartTimer instance) : this() {
        _instance = instance;
     }

     public void Form2_Load(..){

         _instance.Start();

     }
 }
```

en este caso en el load del form2 iniciae el timer invocando el metodo que se expone por la interface, pero puede ser en otro evento si lo necesitas

Comment: error al implementar IStartTimer

Comment: es un error cuando compilas o al ejecutar ? valida que la forma que defines en el la interface es la misma que creas en el form

Comment: @LeandroTuttini , muy útil tu respuesta , pdt: eres una leyenda en los foros de microsoft, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Crea uns instancia del formulario 1 para poder acceder a sus propiedades y controles , esta puedes llamarla desde cualquier lado de tu app

**1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public static  Form1 instance=null;
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    instance = this;

                }
```

**2**

Cambia a public la propiedad del timer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**3**

Accede al timer con "instance" desde tu Formulario2

```
Form1.instance.timer1
```

Tambien podrias acceder al metodo:

```
 Form1.instance.metodocargadatos();
```

Comment: Cuál es la necesidad programar en c# como si fuese vb?